# My entityManager.persist(entity) not is throwing PersistenceException

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, entitymanager

I'm using Netbeans IDE and EclipseLink JPA implementation.

According to Netbeans, this code is valid:

```
public void save(T entity) {        
    EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

But I think, that really valid code is:

```
public void save(T entity) throws PersistenceException {        
    EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PersistenceException extends RuntimeException. This means that is an "unchecked" exception so it does not have to be explicitly declared or handled.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639432/checked-vs-unchecked-exception) for more information.