# Is it redundant to throw specific exception in Java's method?

Tags: java, exception, methods, program-entry-point

Consider the following code snippet.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    ....
}
```

My assumption tells me that: Any exception be it `arrayOutOfBoundsException` or `IOException`, the program will get terminated since there is no catching of the exception (and the exception thrown is not general). However I do see people throws **specific** exception at the method signature.

**My question:** Is it redundant for doing this? (since any exception will cause the program to terminate)

If it is not redundant, what is the reason people do it do this way?

Comment: The -1 is unwarranted. This is a nice question.

Comment: Hey :) I hope you can put a check mark on the answer that most helped you :D *(shameless me)*

Comment: @ADTC sure, you may also upvote this if you find this question helpful.

Comment: Already done :) You see 0 because there's a downvote countering my upvote. -1+1 = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What catches the exception thrown by `main` method?

> *the program will get terminated since there is no catching of the exception*

It may seem that way because the `main` method is where *your* program starts. But actually, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) calls the `main` method and therefore technically it catches and handles any exception thrown by it.

The handling done by JVM is merely to print the stack trace of the exception in the error stream, then terminate your program*. Which is why you see that stack trace in the console (unless the error stream was redirected elsewhere, like a file) before the program terminates.

<sup>* If no other programs (such as live non-daemon threads) are running in the JVM, it will also terminate itself.</sup>

### Why should it be declared?

> *However I do see people throws specific exception at the method signature.* 
>   *Is it redundant for doing this? (since any exception will cause the program to terminate)*

First, I should clarify that by writing `throws`, the programmer is **not** throwing the exception. The programmer is merely declaring that this exception may be thrown by the method, and a caller of the method **must handle it in some way**.

To take your example:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
```

This is most likely added by the programmer because his program calls some method from another class that also declares this. Some common examples are:

```
public FileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException // a constructor can also throw exceptions
FileWriter.write(int c) throws IOException
```

The designer of this `FileWriter` class has made it mandatory for its user (the programmer) to handle the `IOException`. This is called a **checked exception**.

### The two types of exceptions

A checked exception tells the user that during the program run, the scenario causing this exception **is likely** to happen *even though* it normally shouldn't (because we don't live in an ideal world). This suggests an *environmental error* and such an exception can be thrown even in the best program.

The other type of an exception is the **unchecked exception**. The reason why you don't declare `NullPointerException` (an unchecked exception) using `throws` is because the scenario causing it **is not expected** to happen during a normal program run. If it happens, this suggests a *programming error* and a badly written program.

### How do you handle an exception?

There are two ways to handle the exception received in a method.

First is the way the programmer has done in your example. Simply throw that exception back to the caller.

Second is to use a `try-catch` block to handle it internally:

```
public static void main (String [] args) // no need to declare "throws IOException"
{
    try {
        /* some code here that may throw IOException */
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Uhhhh something went wrong!");
        // or some logging can happen
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-6); // a custom error signal can be sent in termination
    }
}
```

### But again, why?

> *If it is not redundant, what is the reason people do it do this way?*

They do it because Java forces checked exceptions to be handled explicitly, while unchecked exceptions can be left unhandled.

As I have already explained the two ways an exception can be handled, it should be noted that programmers may pick one way over another depending on the situation. For some methods it may make more sense to throw a caught exception to the caller, while for others it would make more sense to handle the caught exception internally.

Then there are those lazy programmers who just declares every checked exception with `throws`.

### Notes

Both checked and unchecked exceptions can be handled using either of the two ways above. Unchecked exceptions give you the third choice of not handling it, which in turn gives the caller the choice of handling or not handling it.

If you declare an unchecked exception using `throws`, it will become a checked exception to the caller of your method.

You can also mix and match both ways. For example, you may handle a checked exception internally at any point in the method, even if it is declared to be thrown in the method signature. The `throws` declaration will only take effect where the checked exception is not handled internally.

The `main` method of a class can be called like any other regular static method in your program, just by passing in a `String` array of arguments. It is only special in the sense that the JVM calls this method when the class is started as a Java program. When you manually call the `main` method, you have to handle the checked exceptions that may be thrown.

Comment: @ADTC "The handling done by JVM is merely to print the stack trace of the exception in the error stream, then terminate itself" is not entirely correct. The VM doesn't terminate because of that - it merely terminates the *thread* where the exception occured. The VM then terminates *if* there are no more live non-daemon threads. If you have, for example a Frame open, the VM won't terminate because Swing is still running. (But good detailed answer nontheless +1)

Comment: @Durandal You're absolutely right! Thanks, I will try to word it in without making it too complex to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If some code in `main` throws a [checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639432/checked-vs-unchecked-exception) (like `IOException`), you *have* to declare it in `throws`. The `main` method is just like a normal method in that regard (in fact, it's just like a normal method in *all* regards, except that it's also an entry point for the program).

Comment: It's not even compulsory the programs entry point. When starting a program you have to specify the main class which must contain a method with that signature. If you don't specify a class with such a method as main class, it will not be used as entry point.

Comment: @AndréStannek Yeah, I was trying to keep it simple, since that's not directly relevant to the question. But good point; I'll reword a bit.

Comment: @yshavit What do you mean by `have to declared it in throws` ?

Comment: @user3437460 I meant to add it to the `throws` clause, as in `throws IOException`. You should read up on checked vs unchecked exceptions if you don't understand those. The page I linked to in my answer is a good place to start, and there's plenty of more material out there (including on StackOverflow).