# How to change a person's role in this code

Tags: java, arrays, object, oop

```
public class Person implements Roles{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String[] skills;
    private List<Note> notes;

    public Person(String id, String name, String[] skills) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.skills = skills;
        this.notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String[] getSkills() {
        return this.skills;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSkills(String[] skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public void addNote(String note, String authorName) {
        notes.add(new Note(authorName, note));
    }

    public String listNotes() {
        String result = this.name + " - " + this.id;
        for (Note note: notes) {
            result += "\n" + note.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = this.name + " - " + this.id;
        Arrays.sort(skills);
        for (String skill: skills) {
            result += "\n- " + skills;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (o.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Person Person2 = (Person) o;
        return this.id.equals(Person2.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
public class Student extends Person implements Roles {
    
    private String registration;
    private int year;

    public Student(String id, String name, String registration, int year, String[] skills) {
        super(id, name, skills);
        this.registration = registration;
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = super.name + " - " + super.id + "\nStudent - " + this.registration + " - " + this.year;
        Arrays.sort(skills);
        for (String skill: skills) {
            result += "\n- " + skill;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String listNotes() {
        String result = super.name + " - " + super.id + "\nStudent - " + this.registration + " - " + this.year + "\nNotes:";
        for (Note note: notes) {
            result += "\n" + note.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class Teacher extends Person implements Roles{
    
    private String number;
    private String[] subjects;

    public Teacher(String id, String name, String number, String[] subjects, String[] skills) {
        super(id, name, skills);
        this.number = number;
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = this.name + " - " + this.id + "\nTeacher - " + this.number + " - ";
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= subjects.length - 1; i++) {
            if (i == subjects.length - 1) {
                result += subjects[i];
                break;
            }
            
            result += subjects[i] + ", ";
        }
        Arrays.sort(skills);
        for (String skill: skills) {
            result += "\n- " + skill;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String listNotes() {
        String result = this.name + " - " + this.id + "\nTeacher - " + this.number + " - ";
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= subjects.length - 1; i++) {
            if (i == subjects.length - 1) {
                result += subjects[i] + "\n:";
                break;
            }
            
            result += subjects[i] + ", ";
        }
        
        for (Note note: notes) {
            result += "\n" + note.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The system must be able to register people, students and teachers. I created a superclass Person with Student and Teacher subclasses, and an interface to store in a people map.

And now I need a way to change the roles of those already registered people, like a person becoming a teacher, or a student being out of a role.

Comment: This is a weird design. Why is `Role` an interface? A person "*has* a role", not "*is* a role".

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to change the roles of those already registered people, like a person becoming a teacher, or a student being out of a role.

Before I answer your question, I would like to point out a few *key* design mistakes. (you can skip ahead, but highly discouraged)

1. You do not need to implement the `Roles` interface multiple times in your `Student` and `Teacher` classes, as your superclass `Person` already did that.

> As [Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca) said in this comment:
>
> > This is a weird design. Why is Role an interface? A person "has a role", not "is a role".

2. As [Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca) said above, `Person` class should not be inheriting from the `Roles` interface, as that indicates that a person "*is a* role", not "*has a* role". Your `Person` class should be referencing `Roles` instead (you can read more about [inheritance vs composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36162730/19830843)).
3. Furthermore, I do not think that `Roles` is suitable as an interface in your context. An enum or a set of static constants seems more appropriate here.

To answer your question. By fixing the *key* mistakes pointed out above, adding an additional check, a custom exception, and a secondary constructor; you will get presumingly what you wanted.

Here is the bare version of your classes for the sake of simplicity, the rest can be easily added in.

```java
public enum Role {
    NONE,
    STUDENT,
    TEACHER
}
```

```java
public class UnrelatedRoleException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final String EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "%s cannot be casted %s!";

    public UnrelatedRoleException(final Class<? extends Person> from, final Class<? extends Person> to) {
        super(String.format(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, from.getSimpleName(), to.getSimpleName()));
    }
}
```

```java
public class Person {
    private Role role;

    public Person() {
        this(Role.NONE);
    }

    public Person(final Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    protected Person(final Person person) {
        if (!isApplicable(person.role)) {
            throw new UnrelatedRoleException(this.getClass(), this.getClass());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param role the updated role
     */
    public void setRole(final Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    /**
     * @return the person role
     */
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    /**
     * @param role the role to check against
     *
     * @return true if the role is compatible with {@link Person}
     */
    public boolean isApplicable(final Role role) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Student extends Person {
    public Student() {
        super(Role.STUDENT);
    }

    public Student(final Person person) {
        super(person);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable(final Role role) {
        return role == Role.STUDENT;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Teacher extends Person {
    public Teacher() {
        super(Role.TEACHER);
    }

    public Teacher(final Person person) {
        super(person);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable(final Role role) {
        return role == Role.TEACHER;
    }
}
```

This is how it can be used:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Person person = new Person();

        // updating the person's role to Student
        person.setRole(Role.STUDENT);
        final Student student = new Student(person);

        // updating the person's role to TEACHER
        person.setRole(Role.TEACHER);
        final Teacher teacher = new Teacher(person);
    }
}
```

The way this is designed:

1. `Person` instance can be constructed with `Role.NONE` as the default role or pass down your own `Role`.
2. `Person` will be treated as the common type between `Student` and `Teacher`. Therefore, it will be safe to use.
3. There are two ways to retrieve an instance of
   `Student` and `Teacher`.

   3.1. If you have an instance of `Person`, change the
   `Person`'s role to `Role.STUDENT`/`Role.TEACHER`, and
   pass down the `Person` instance to `Student`/`Teacher`
   to retain the data.

   3.2. Otherwise, create a new instance of
   `Student`/`Teacher`.

**There is something to note**: when you add the relevant methods to the *subclasses* of `Person`, I urge you to include a check that checks if the role persists with the current class (via `#isApplicable(role)`), and throw an unchecked exception ([checked vs unchecked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639432/checked-vs-unchecked-exception)) if the role is no longer relevant.

Otherwise, the subclasses' role can be changed to something not relevant to the class, and presumingly break your requirement; as you should not be able to process duties that are no longer relevant to your role.

Feel free to ask any questions that you may have.