# Is Java "throws" like an inverse of C++ "noexcept"?

Tags: java, c++, exception

I don't fully understand what the `throws` keyword in Java is for.

In particular, I can't seem to find clear information about what happens if I were to throw an exception type `T` from a Java function which declares that only exceptions of type `Y` can be thrown.

For example, something like this:

```java
void testFunction () throws SomeExceptionType {
    throw new SomeDifferentExceptionType();
}
```

In this case I have attempted to illustrate that the expected exception type does not match the exception type which is actually thrown. Is this syntactically legal Java? If so, what happens at runtime?

---

I come from a C++ background, and in C++ we have the concept of `noexcept`. This keyword is used to mark functions as `noexcept` which means that they are not permitted to throw an exception. If a function marked `noexcept` *does* throw an exception, then `std::terminate` is immediately called, which borks program execution.

`std::terminate` is effectively like a "goto" statement in that it takes you to the end of program execution, quitting the program runtime. It may also do some stack clean-up for RAII, [this is actually implementation defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate), apparently.

So, is Java's `throws` statement equivalent to C++ `noexcept`, but inverted?

---

Although there are lots of questions here which ask how to use `throws`, I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this specific question about what happens if you throw something different to the exception type specified with `throws`.

---

Edit: I understand that this is only really relevant to the concept of checked exception types, because unchecked exception types "do not interact with" the `throws` keyword. Knowing this doesn't however provide an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: I don't know enough about Java to confirm but do note that in C++ the exception specification before C++11 used the same syntax, and might be why Java uses it.  You can read about how the old C++ way worked here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec

Comment: I suppose you want first to learn about checked/unchecked https://www.baeldung.com/java-checked-unchecked-exceptions

Comment: @teapot418 isn't the first part only the case for checked Exceptions?

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yes, knowing the difference between both doesn't get any closer to answering the question. I knew about both before asking this.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant you just cannot compile code which tries to throw checked exception not mentioned in throws, and answer posted also tells the same `If not, you will get a compilation error.`

Comment: @IłyaBursov Ok that is the answer I was looking for. I didn't understand that part of the answer. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of  [Checked vs Unchecked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639432/checked-vs-unchecked-exception)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No it isn't

Comment: I think it does, because it explains what checked exceptions are, why you must use `throws` with checked exceptions, and that you get a compilation error otherwise if a checked exception can be thrown by code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I knew the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions prior to asking this question, so that would make it somewhat pointless to have asked the question if it was indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I did not ask "what is an unchecked or checked exception" I asked what happens if you try to throw one or the other from a function which doesn't declare them with `throws`. It's a totally different question, even if they are about the same subject matter.

Comment: From the [topvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639560/466862): _"Compiler will never force you to catch such exception or force you to declare it in the method using `throws` keyword."_.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Of what relevance is that

Comment: You say you asked _"[..] what happens if you try to throw one or the other from a function which doesn't declare them with throws."_ And the answer is that for unchecked exceptions the compiler doesn't force you to catch or declare `throws`, and for checked exception (for which I neglected to include a relevant quote from the duplicate in my previous comment), the compiler will force you to add `throws` or catch them. In other words, the duplicate does answer your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Again, of what relevance is that? Two questions may be different but have similar, or even the same, answer

Answer (score 3):

In Java there are two types of exceptions - checked and unchecked. Checked exceptions are all the subclasses of `Exception` except those which are subclasses of `RuntimeException`.

Which means exceptions which are descendants of `RuntimeException` are unchecked exceptions.

The throws clause declares which checked exceptions the method is allowed to throw. It can throw any unchecked exception, but only checked exceptions which are declared in its throws clause (or their subclasses).

It has nothing to do with `noexcept`.

Syntactically what you wrote is not correct, because you are supposed to write `throw new SomeDifferentExceptionType()` - you can't throw a class. But assuming that's what you meant, if `SomeDifferentExceptionType` is unchecked, it will also work well. If not, you will get a compilation error.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. It was intended to be pseduocode, but I will edit it to make it clearer. I didn't know the exact syntax.

Comment: Btw this doesn't answer the question - at all. Is it possible to throw a checked exception which isn't declared with `throws`, or not? Is this a runtime error? A compile time error?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant what keeps you from trying yourself? Just write an empty method where all you do is `throw new IOException();`, for example. Then you'll see that this is a compiler error.

Comment: @QBrute I don't have a JVM at work! Otherwise yes I would try it, but that might not necessarily give a clear understanding. The alternative might be to buy a textbook - but I also don't have one of those to hand (or even own one)