# Eclipse warn about uncaught Error

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling, compiler-warnings

When failing to catch a subclass of `Exception`, Eclipse will issue a compilation warning (red).

However, when an subclass of `Error` is uncaught, no warning is issued, making it easy to forget including the `throws SomethingError` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the difference between checked (subclasses of Exception excluding RuntimeException) and unchecked exceptions (subclasses of RuntimeException or Error).

- Oracle [note on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)
- Stackoverflow: [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explaination)

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially to avoid having to add exception handling code to every trivial line of code that you write. This question explains that really well: [Why are Runtime Exceptions "unchecked" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656376/why-are-runtime-exceptions-unchecked-in-java)